# Batch Apex StartTime and EndTime

Tags: apex, batch

I have written a batch class. I want to know when my batch class gets started and ended. How can I get this information?

Comment: why don't you just use 2 variables at start of you batch class and end of your batch and then check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the time stamp under Apex Jobs:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about performing DML in Start and finish method of the batch? You would need to save your instance variable during all batch transaction using Database.stateful . You would need a custom object to track this though.

Here is the code how i acheived this.

```
global class deleteAccounts implements Database.Batchable, Database.Stateful    {
 global final String Query;
 global Job__C batchInfo;

 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
  batchInfo=Job__C(name='MyBatch',startDate__C=System.now());
 insert batchInfo;
  return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List scope) {
    //Your Logic
```

}

```
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //your logic 
        batchInfo.endDate__C=System.now();
        update batchInfo;
   });
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**AsyncApexJob** : 
Represents an individual Apex sharing recalculation job, a batch Apex job, a method with the future annotation, or a job that implements Queueable.

**Usage** :
Use this object to query Apex batch jobs in your organization.

**Referenced Link**:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm